# Como não permitir que um caractere seja digitado no textbox, com JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho um Textbox:

```
<input type="text" name="indice" class="number">
```

Queria que quando uma pessoa digitasse uma vírgula nesse Textbox ela fosse bloqueada e não aparecesse no Textbox.

Como fazer isso da melhor maneira?

Não gostaria que se a pessoa mantivesse pressionada a virgula, ela fosse aparecendo no Textbox e só depois fosse apagada, foi o máximo que eu consegui fazer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Se seu objetivo for impedir não apenas que ele seja **digitado**, mas que ele seja usado como valor de qualquer forma (ex.: copiar e colar) eu sugiro ouvir a propriedade `input` e ajustar o valor conforme sua regra (no caso, eliminar as vírgulas):

```javascript
$('input').on("input", function(e) {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/,/g, ""));
});
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/2x5WC/1/) Em alguns browsers mais antigos, talvez seja necessário também ouvir por `propertychange` (mas creio que `input` é amplamente suportado).

Dessa forma, não importa se foi digitada a vírgula no teclado "normal", no teclado numérico, Ctrl+C Ctrl+V ou mesmo Right-click e "colar". O valor será mantido sem a vírgula em todos os casos, e nenhum glitch visual irá ocorrer.

P.S. Veja também [essa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9205164/520779) que fiz há algum tempo no SOEN, para mais detalhes.

Comment: Essa solução é melhor que a minha, eu não conhecia esse evento! Fica a referência: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/input

Comment: Ótima solução. Vou utilizá-la

Comment: Esse tem o problema chato de não manter o cursor no lugar certo. Alguma forma de fazer isso?

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Cara, eu estou com o mesmo problema! Vou até dar uma olhada no plugin indicado por utluiz, pois no momento não conheço nenhuma solução. Já andei dando umas lidas em métodos para se manipular o cursor no browser, mas desisti devido à complexidade...

Answer (score 11):

Você provavelmente tentou interceptar a tecla no evento `keyup`. Se utilizar o `keydown`, a vírgula não chega a aparecer.

Exemplo em jQuery:

```
$('input').keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.which === 188 || e.which === 110) { // 188 é vírgula e 110 virgula do teclado numérico
        return false;   
        // ou:
        // e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

[Demo no jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2x5WC/).

Comment: Amigo, obrigado pela resposta. Mas não funcionou. Coloquei um alert antes do return false para testar. O alert aparece quando aperto virgula, mas depois a virgula também aparece.

Comment: Mas sem o `alert` funciona. Você precisa mesmo do `alert`? Se não quiser usar `return false`, `e.preventDefault()` basta.

Comment: É realmente com o alert não funciona. Só usei para testar. Não funcionava pois eu estava usando a virgula do teclado numerico. Voce sabe qual o numero dela?

Comment: Acho que é 110.

Comment: Eu dei um upvote, mas sinceramente não ficaria muito satisfeito em usar uma solução com esses códigos fixos. O que acontece se eu copiar um caracter de vírgula e colar no campo?

Comment: @JoaoPaulo Fique à vontade para aceitar a resposta do mgibsonbr em vez da minha. A dele é melhor, funciona em mais casos.

Comment: Essa opção funcionaria bem em alguma situação que tivesse que bloquear o enter por exemplo...

Comment: @KennyRafael Verdade, já usei esse método muitas vezes para bloquear o enter.

Answer (score 11):

A resposta do @bfavaretto responde diretamente a questão, mas conforme comentei, eu não usaria um filtro de caracteres deste tipo para impedir a entrada não desejada.

Isso pode ser facilmente burlado, mesmo inconscientemente (sem querer), se o usuário copiar um texto e colar no campo (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> e <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>).

Uma opção par não reinventar a roda é usar um plugin como o [**jquery-plugin-filter-text-input**](http://www.thimbleopensource.com/tutorials-snippets/jquery-plugin-filter-text-input), cuja **vantagem é que ao digitar o caractere inválido ele preserva o local do cursor**, o que não funciona somente ao tentar colar um conteúdo inválido.

Comment: A coisa fica ainda pior: se o usuário clicar com o botão direito e escolher "colar" no *dropdown*, ele pode inserir um valor incorreto sem que qualquer tecla tenha sido pressionada...

Comment: @mgibsonbr É verdade, pois algumas pessoas acham que bloquear combinações com a tecla `ctrl` é uma solução.

Comment: Outra sugestão é usar um dos trocentos plugins de Mask. Pessoalmente gosto [desse daqui](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/).

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Já usei algumas vezes esse plugin, é muito bom. Mas no caso específico desta pergunta, o OP não quer uma máscara, ele quer impedir um determinado caractere na caixa, sem uma formatação específica.

Comment: utluiz, por isso deixei em comentário ao invés de uma resposta a parte. Acredito que para *inputs* a mascara seja melhor do ponto de vista de usabilidade. E, como em algum momento acredito que esse site se tornará público e indexado pelo Google, achei útil deixar um comentário para quem não conhece a opção.

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma bem simples seria simplesmente desabilitar o input utilizando a propriedade disabled ( `<input name="" value="" disabled />` ). Dessa forma você pode manipular o valor desse campo e não permite que o usuário digite nada através do teclado.

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa com JavaScript puro:

```
const input = document.querySelector("#input");

input.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {

    if(e.key === ",") {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
  
});
```

Neste exemplo, estamos verificando os dígitos neste input e fazendo o teste no if se a key é o caractere que não pode ser inserido, caso seja simplesmente cortamos o evento com preventDefault.

Caso hajam outros caracteres que não possam ser inseridos, é possível fazer uma verificação se o caractere está em um array.